# Bash - Getting the directory of user input

Tags: linux, bash

In bash, I ask a user to enter the absolute path of a file, such as `dir/to/the/file.txt` and then go to that directory and run some commands. But I just cant get to the supplied directory.

I've tried the scripts below, and if it doesn't throw me an error, it just outputs a single "."

```sh
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Please Enter Path:" $r1
parent=$(dirname "${r1}")
echo "${scriptdir}"


#!/bin/bash
read -p "Please Enter Path:" $r1
parent=$(readlink -f "$(dirname "$r1")")
cd $parent


#!/bin/bash
read -p "Please Enter Path:" $r1
parent="$(basename "$(dirname "$r1")")"
echo "$parent"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `read -p "Please Enter Path:" $r1` -> `read -p "Please Enter Path:" r1`. Generally quote variables everywhere, `cd "$parent"`. It outputs a single `.`, because `r1` variable is empty, you basically run `dirname ""`, which outputs `.`.

Comment: I dont understand what you said much, I have tried with quotes and without still can not. thou I have tried above commands with many options.

Comment: It's not about quoting. It is because you  provided a null string instead of  a variable name where `read` would store the value being read. An alternative would be to not write anything for a variable, in which case the answer would be stored in the special variable `REPLY`. For instance `read -p "Enter Path"; parent=$(dirname $REPLY)`.

Answer (score 4):

As KamilCuk pointed out, when executing the `read` command, it should put the supplied value into the `r1` variable. This is done *without* the `$`.

So:

```sh
read -p "Please Enter Path: " r1
```

instead of:

```sh
read -p "Please Enter Path: " $r1
```

Also, when printing a variable, the brackets are not required:

```sh
echo "$parent"
```

instead of

```sh
echo "${parent}"
```

If you apply these fixed, the first script should work:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Please Enter Path:" r1
parent=$(dirname "$r1")
cd "$parent"
```

EDIT: The user Adhoc added a good remark: if we add the `-r` parameter to the `read` command, backslashes will not behave as escape characters. This will change the script as follows:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Please Enter Path:" -r r1
parent=$(dirname "$r1")
cd "$parent"
```

Comment: I would even suggest using `read -p "Please Enter Path:" -r r1`
Especially if the path ends up being a Windows path, you will have backslashes that will get mangled if you don't use -r.
More at https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2162